# Select image from Gallery using Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, image-gallery, android-gallery, onactivityresult

I am trying to select and bring image from gallery, I could bring for 4.4.2 version but 5.0.0 or above it is not working.

When imageview1 is clicked:

```
imageview1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent galeri_int = new Intent();
                galeri_int.setType("image/*");
                galeri_int.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                galeri_int.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);


                startActivityForResult(galeri_int,44);

                Log.d("tık","tıklandı");


            }
        });
```

OnActivityResult:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){


        InputStream stream = null;

        if(data  !=null){

        try {
            stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
            bitmapx = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
            stream.close();
            Bitmap resized = resize(bitmapx,1000,1000);

           imageview.setImageBitmap(resized);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        }


    }
```

It is not working for 5.0.0 or above so what should I do?

Comment: `not working for 5.0.0 or above `. You should start teling what not works. I bed the first bitmap that you try to generate is `null`. You should have told us.

Comment: Images are not seen(When user click imageview1, In gallery screen, images are not seen. Just their size are seen their thumbnails are not seen) if I use this code in versions 5.0 or above. Finally, my answer is working for all versions. In gallery screen all images are seen.

Comment: You are not even reacting on that the bitmap will be null. Are you a programmer?

Comment: No, it is not null. It will be never it is working.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent();  
    intent.setType("image/*");  
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);  
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose Picture"), 1);

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    if(resultCode==RESULT_CANCELED)
    {
        // action cancelled
    }
    if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)
    {
        Uri selectedimg = data.getData();
        imageView.setImageBitmap(MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedimg));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Finally, I solved my problem with changing click listener.

```
imageview1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

        startActivityForResult(i,44);

        Log.d("tık","tıklandı");


    }
});
```

Comment: `I solved my problem with changing click listener`. No. Your on click listener is the same. But you changed the action of the used intent. Which is really a bad idea.

Comment: Why a bad idea? It solved my problem now it is working for all versions.